# How can I extract the number of days from a hh:mm:ss format in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, conversion, time

I have an excel worksheet with hours in hh:mm:ss format and I was looking for a way to extract the number of DAYS from this format. 
IE, let's say I have 32:40:00, I want to get 1day 8hrs 40mins.

After a lot of searching nothing I found so far worked for me. Can anyone help?

PS: The DAY function seems to work, as long as the number of days is less than 31, else it returns the remaining days after 31 days has passed.

Answer (score 2):

`DAY()` returns day of month, not absolute number of days.

As Excel stores dates as integer part is day, decimal part is time, you can use these formulas:

- day: `=INT(A3)`
- time: `=A3-B3`

[image]

---

There is also a good help page [how Excel manage date and time](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214094/how-to-use-dates-and-times-in-excel), the core information is here:

> Excel stores all dates as integers and all times as decimal fractions. With this system, Excel can add, subtract, or compare dates and times just like any other numbers, and all dates are manipulated by using this system.
>
> In this system, the serial number 1 represents 1/1/1900 12:00:00 a.m. Times are stored as decimal numbers between .0 and .99999, where .0 is 00:00:00 and .99999 is 23:59:59. The date integers and time decimal fractions can be combined to create numbers that have a decimal and an integer portion. For example, the number 32331.06 represents the date and time 7/7/1988 1:26:24 a.m.

Comment: Is there documentation for this?  This is pretty useful.

Comment: @Nelson: yes, there is, please see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

First, be aware of the three things

- Excel dates "start" at 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00
- You want a display the date in a format that Excel does not understand
- You will not be able to do calculations based on the result

Your "date" is actually stored as the number 1.36 in your cell. It is the cell display format of [h]:mm:ss that shows you 32:40:00.

Considering your value is stored in A1, you could use this formula

```
=concatenate(int(A1)," days ",text(A1,"HH:MM"))
```